# Using Eclipse how to use login screen

Tags: android

I am very new to programming so please be easy on me. I have been able to create a login screen using the following code

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

And of course the xml code as well but thats not needed. What I need to know is if anyone could help with an example code possibly on how I could have a user actually login. There information is already on the website, Ijust need to know how to make a api call to retrive there information. Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: website means somewhere else? not on phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a [HttpConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.html), although that may be deprecated in the near future.  Try looking something up and doing a little more research.  Make sure to thoroughly read the page I linked.